# HP hardware problems on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, hardware

I've installed Xubuntu to my detachable computer Pavilion x2 but some components are not working (speakers, card reader etc.). and system cannot see the battery so i cannot see the battery percentage.

I thought it is related with drivers. But when i entered additional drivers there was no specific  drivers there is only one driver and system names it "unknown: unknown" and gives me 2 option:

1. Using processor microcode firmware for intel cpus from intel-microcode (proprietary)
2. Do not use this device

I selected 1 but still there is no change.

I've read that the system must have detected the hardwares automatically but my system didn't do it.

What should I do to make system detect these hardwares?

Here is the ss of additional drivers part:

[image: here is the ss of additional drivers part]

Comment: Unfortunately, yours is what I call a "glorified **Windows** tablet". Meaning: It works fine with Windows only. Any Bay Trail/Cherry Trail, of "Z" and "X" series, is poorly supported in Linux.

Comment: Have you tried any other distro (Ubuntu/Fedora/etc.) on your machine and found it to be working? If yes, there is a possibility that we may try and import that specific kernel module. Or maybe these issues are already solved in a newer kernel version (it happens sometimes). Evaluate Fedora Live and you'll come to know if that's the case.